# access Slickgrid group header text

Tags: slickgrid

I'm struggling to find a way to dynamically populate a textbox with the text that appears in a slick grid group header when that group header is selected (clicked). Anything that anyone can offer would be appreciated.

I have tried using the row select model and the on selected rows changed event. However, these do not seem to fire when group headers are selected.  Ive also tried using the div class for the selected group header to fire a jQuery event... with no luck.  I have also searched for anything similar on this site, as well as other google results.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us specific code, but from what I can see, the Group Header is a child of the HeaderScroller element, which should route clicks to the `onHeaderClick` event. Have you tried handling that event? You should be able to work out the triggering element from the `event` object.